# convert large to long

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to convert data to a long format. It's a repeated measure design, with 3 conditions.
This is what I have :

| participant id | measure 1 (cond1) | measure 1 (cond2) | measure 1 (cond3) | measure2 (cond1) | measure2 (cond2) | measure2 (cond3) | measure3 (cond1) | measure3(cond2) | measure3 (cond3) | age | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

And this is what I would like:

| participant id | condition | measure1 | measure2 | measure3 | age | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |

I Tried `data_long <- gather(df, condition_measure1, measure1, measure1_cond1, measure1_cond2, measure1_cond3, factor_key=TRUE)`

It works, but if I don't know how to put all 3 conditions in long format. I tried repeating the same code but for measure2, it did not work, it added another 3 rows for each participant.
Can you hep me ? I a very new to R, so forgive me, I just want to convert my data and go back to Jamovi ^^
Thank you!

edit: here is the data

```
structure(list(num_pp = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), nombre_dp1 = c(24, 
14, 2, 6, 6, 21), nombre_dp05 = c(20, 28, 2, 9, 8, 21), nombre_dp0 = c(24, 
20, 4, 11, 8, 20), jugement_causal_dp1 = c("Oui", "Oui", "Oui", 
"Oui", "Oui", "Oui"), jugement_causal_dp05 = c("Non", "Oui", 
"Non", "Non", "Oui", "Non"), jugement_causal_dp0 = c("Non", "Non", 
"Oui", "Non", "Non", "Non"), confiance_dp1 = c(90, 80, 63, 80, 
90, 80), confiance_dp05 = c(60, 50, 86, 65, 50, 90), confiance_dp0 = c(65, 
60, 55, 43, 50, 80), age = c(33, 22, 20, 20, 18, 18), genre = c("Masculin", 
"Feminin", "Feminin", "Feminin", "Feminin", "Feminin"), etude = c("L1", 
"L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1"), ordre = c("dp_05|dp_1|dp_0", "dp_0|dp_1|dp_05", 
"dp_0|dp_1|dp_05", "dp_0|dp_05|dp_1", "dp_1|dp_05|dp_0", "dp_1|dp_05|dp_0"
), wdif_dp1dp05 = c(-4, 14, 0, 3, 2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: I think you want something like this: `df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(participant_id, age, gender), names_to = c(".value", condition"), names_pattern = "(measure\\d+) \\((cond\\d+)\\)")` but can't be sure without data

Comment: @RuiBarradas ok, I posted sample data (I think!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data OP provided, you could directly use `pivot_longer` as shown below:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(matches('_dp\\d+$'), names_to = c('.value', 'dp'), 
                names_pattern = '(.*)_(\\w+)')
# A tibble: 18 × 10
   num_pp   age genre    etude ordre  wdif_dp1dp05 dp    nombre jugement_causal confiance
    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>
 1      1    33 Masculin L1    dp_05…           -4 dp1       24 Oui                    90
 2      1    33 Masculin L1    dp_05…           -4 dp05      20 Non                    60
 3      1    33 Masculin L1    dp_05…           -4 dp0       24 Non                    65
 4      2    22 Feminin  L1    dp_0|…           14 dp1       14 Oui                    80
 5      2    22 Feminin  L1    dp_0|…           14 dp05      28 Oui                    50
 6      2    22 Feminin  L1    dp_0|…           14 dp0       20 Non                    60
 7      3    20 Feminin  L1    dp_0|…            0 dp1        2 Oui                    63
 8      3    20 Feminin  L1    dp_0|…            0 dp05       2 Non                    86
 9      3    20 Feminin  L1    dp_0|…            0 dp0        4 Oui                    55
10      4    20 Feminin  L1    dp_0|…            3 dp1        6 Oui                    80
11      4    20 Feminin  L1    dp_0|…            3 dp05       9 Non                    65
12      4    20 Feminin  L1    dp_0|…            3 dp0       11 Non                    43
13      5    18 Feminin  L1    dp_1|…            2 dp1        6 Oui                    90
14      5    18 Feminin  L1    dp_1|…            2 dp05       8 Oui                    50
15      5    18 Feminin  L1    dp_1|…            2 dp0        8 Non                    50
16      6    18 Feminin  L1    dp_1|…            0 dp1       21 Oui                    80
17      6    18 Feminin  L1    dp_1|…            0 dp05      21 Non                    90
18      6    18 Feminin  L1    dp_1|…            0 dp0       20 Non                    80
```

We use `.value` within the `names_to` to ensure that the 3 measure values are spread across different columns.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I would like ! But I don't understand the "Name pattern" and I cannot use the code on my data, I edited my question and posted my data, could you give me the same code for my data  ?

Comment: @liz using your data, what is measure and what is condition? ie do you want the columns `nomre`, `judgement_causal` and `confiance`?

Comment: Yes, the 3 measures (columns) are nombre, jugement_causal and confiance. The 3 conditions are dp1, dp05 and dp0.

Comment: @liz try `df %>% pivot_longer(matches('_dp\\d+$'), names_to = c('.value', 'dp'), names_pattern = '(.*)_(\\w+)')`

Comment: I think it worked ! But how do you export the new dataframe into a osv/excel file ? And view the new data ? If i do `view(df)` it shows the original data

Comment: @liz you need to store the results in a variable. ie `results <- df %>% pivot_longer ....` now do `View(results)`

Comment: @Onyambu you left a quite sweet thoughtful message on my answer (thank you), but then it disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is something like this:

```
df <- structure(list(`participant id` = c(1, 2, 3), `measure 1 (cond1)` = c(10, 
12, 8), `measure 1 (cond2)` = c(15, 14, 9), `measure 1 (cond3)` = c(20, 
18, 10), `measure2 (cond1)` = c(25, 22, 15), `measure2 (cond2)` = c(30, 
28, 19), `measure2 (cond3)` = c(35, 30, 22), `measure3 (cond1)` = c(40, 
38, 25), `measure3 (cond2)` = c(45, 42, 28), `measure3 (cond3)` = c(50, 
48, 32), age = c(25, 30, 27), gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

You can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- pivot_longer(df,
             cols = starts_with("measure"), 
             names_pattern = "measure ?(\\d+) \\(cond(\\d+)\\)",
                names_to = c("measure", "condition")) |>
    mutate(condition = as.integer(condition),
           measure = as.integer(measure))

# Output:
   `participant id`   age gender measure condition value
              <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <int>     <int> <dbl>
 1                1    25 Male         1         1    10
 2                1    25 Male         1         2    15
 3                1    25 Male         1         3    20
 4                1    25 Male         2         1    25
 5                1    25 Male         2         2    30
 6                1    25 Male         2         3    35
 7                1    25 Male         3         1    40
 8                1    25 Male         3         2    45
 9                1    25 Male         3         3    50
10                2    30 Female       1         1    12
# ℹ 17 more rows
```

To make it wide again:

```
df |> pivot_wider(names_from = measure, values_from = value, names_prefix = "measure")
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did something weird, I still have 9 rows per participant instead of 3..

Comment: @liz you can pivot it wider again if you want, but it would be less tidy

Comment: @Onyambu see the comments above

Comment: idk @Onyambu I think it's good practice to make the data tidy before transforming it. Someone was giving me grief for not tidying yesterday, and now today I am given grief for tidying. One cannot win